# Finding sales growth from cumulative totals over period in SQL

Tags: sql

[image]

[image: Need help with Creating the Sales Growth column]

```
SELECT CUST_ID,CONTACTS 
        Sum("CONTACTS") Over (PARTITION by "CUST_ID" Order By "end_Period"  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as RunningContacts,
        "SALES",
        Sum("SALES") Over (PARTITION by  "CUST_ID" Order By "end_Period"  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as RunningSales,
    end_Period
FROM    Table2
```

I have currently created the Running growth column in excel formula is (New Runningsales - Previous Running sales) / Previous RunningSales.

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to create the Running Growth column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
select t.*,
       RunningSales / (Running - Sales) - 1
from (< your query here > ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL derived table can hold a query to aggregate sales by period, and you an join such to itself to compare each period to the prior period.